# How to check if any of the li's are selected or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id='id'>
 <ul id='ul'>
  <li id='1' class="">a</li>
  <li id='2' class="">a</li>
  <li id='3' class="">a</li>
  <li id='4' class="select">a</li>
  <li id='5' class="">a</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

How do I know if any of the `<li>`s have a `select` class? If found, how do I remove that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will remove the `select` class from all `<li>` elements that have it:

```
$('li.select').each(function() { $(this).removeClass('select'); });
```

Comment: taken the words out of my mou--er hands

Comment: If i have a anchor tag instead of li then $('a.select').each(function() { $(this).removeClass('select'); }); should work?

Comment: By the way, jaquiline, I noticed this is your first question here, be sure to click the check mark next to the answer which best answers your question to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

To find if any li is selected use

```
$('#ul > .select');
```

and use removeClass to remove select

```
.removeClass('select');
```

Answer (score 1):

use

> removeClass

```
  $('#ul li').removeClass("select");
```

to find this class is exist ?
use

> hasClass

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
$("#ul > li").filter(function(index) { return $(this).hasClass("select"); }).removeClass("select");
```

EDIT:

Interesting [test case](http://jsperf.com/filter-performance) on jsperf showing that indeed, filter is the slowest method, while selector method is the fastest.

Comment: i would think this has too much gravy/mustard though IMHO

Comment: I suppose you are right. A simple `$("#ul > .select").removeClass("select")` would work. But this is funner to write! ;) Definitely not as efficient though. :)

Comment: it does look more "hardcore" though. just not a fan since im using jquery for the simplicity :) it's good to see other implementations though, pretty unique than the 3 other answers haha

Comment: @Andrew for sure, I upvoted your answer as it's the cleanest and simplest IMO. :)

Comment: Thanks `:)`. Also, doesn't mean hardcore isn't fun, as you say, because that's how one learns! In practice though, _lex parsimoniae_ wins.